# Changing "index.php" Within The Address

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am developing a website in which i want to change my page `home.php` into page `home`

I tried this `.htaccess` code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php page=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Just this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# Replace html with your file extension, eg: php, htm, asp
```

This will work on local, but when you release your project don't forget to check if rewrite is enabled for the current server.